# Hide/Show image on one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could you help me to make something like this (javascript,jquery...)

http://m.uploadedit.com/b016/1370729652780.gif

Nn click '1' show 'pic1' and hide 'pic2' and vice versa

Comment: erm...no. Please read the [faq]

Comment: It is unclear if you have tried anything at all. Currently it is difficult to tell with which parts you have trouble. It seem like you have this homework to do and are asking others to solve it for you.

Comment: how to call two functions on one click?

Comment: To call 2 functions you can do this http://jsfiddle.net/GgUyW/5/ or this http://jsfiddle.net/GgUyW/6/

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/qYCUJ/ Try this

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="showhide_menu('btn1');">Show/Hide.  </button>

<button onclick="showhide_menu('btn2');">Show/Hide.  </button>

<div id="btn1" class="btn" style="display:none;">
<img src="http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834"/>
</div>

<div id="btn2" class="btn" style="display:none;">
<img src="http://jenntgrace.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/2.png"/>
</div>
```

**jQuery JS**

```
window.showhide_menu = function(id){
$('.btn:not(#'+id+')').hide();
$("#" + id).toggle();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, tnx a lot @dubstaphone

Answer (score 1):

To call two functions on one button, set the button attribute `onclick="hideandshow()"` then define the functions in your javascript file or `<script>` tag:

```
function hide(){
    ... //your code here
}
function show(){
    ... //your code here
}
function hideandshow(){
    hide();
    show();
    return true;
}
```